# how to copy a file from remotehost to localhost by using tcl-expect

Tags: tcl, expect

Here i am making a connection b/w two machines using telnet and in the remote host i am creating a file named "file.txt" and storing the result of the "ls" command execution in the file.txt. now i need to send the file to the local host. i dont know how to do it. anybody who knows it kindly help me out here.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect 
spawn telnet <machine ip> 
expect "login:" 
send "<username>\n" 
expect "Password:" 
send "<password>\n" 
expect "bash"
send " ls > file.txt\r "
expect "bash"
send " cat file.txt \r "
expect "bash"
send " command for copying file to the localhost computer\r"
expect "bash"
send "exit\r"
```

Comment: An obligatory comment: do you really cannot use SSH to do this natively?

Comment: good time to get to know it, really. See the comment thread after the Donal's answer for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're strongly recommended to use `ssh` and `scp` for this task.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

### Factor these out
set user <username>
set pass <password>
set host <machineIP>

### Get the file list into a file remotely
spawn ssh $user@$host sh -c {ls -1 >file.txt}
expect {
    "Password:" {
        send "$pass\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {
        close
    }
}
### Copy the file to the local machine
spawn scp $user@${host}:file.txt .
expect {
    "Password:" {
        send "$pass\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {
        close
    }
}
```

Comment: why cant we use telnet for this above program?

Comment: what is the function of this line. i mean what does it do?
-re {(?n)(^.*)$}

Comment: Some notes: I use `ls -1` because that *guarantees* one file per line. I use `${host}` because `:` is legal in variable names but I don't want it to be one. I normally use `ssh_agent` (or the `-i` option to `ssh` and `scp`) so that I don't need to supply a password at all, but that requires some setup on the other side.

Comment: Telnet is _totally_ insecure. Trivial to sniff and spoof. Almost everything (except for certain routers, IIRC) supports ssh, in fact far more than actually support telnet these days.

Comment: The RE (from the old version of my answer) matches a line of output, placing the matched text in `$expect_out(1,string)`.

Comment: so ssh would be able to provide secure transfer of files.

Comment: @deva, not only SSH is secure, it is a *shell.* This means you can do something like: `$ ssh user@host 'tar -cf - /some/dir' | tar -C / -xf -` to create tar archive on `host` and pipe its output to another tar running in extract mode on local host, all this happening in real time without extra fuss like `expect`. Also SSH supports public-key authentication which can be used to completely eliminate any scripting needed to automate authentication.

Comment: The only reason I've used expect above is because I was allowing for a possible password prompt. If a key is set up, you can automate all this with _anything_.

Comment: I should also mention that the above code is set up so that if you do set up `ssh-agent`, it will continue to work; it only supplies the password if it is asked for instead of giving it unilaterally.

Comment: By the way, to automate SSH operations in case the target site insists on using keyboard-interactive authentication method, there's a tool, sshpass (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) which can be used for automation--the password can be stored in a file.